# Show that the collection of open rectangles is equivalent to the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

**Exercise** Show that the collection of open rectangles is equivalent to the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$

In order to show that, I need to show that

- every point inside a Euclidean open ball has a rectangle neighborhood contained in the ball
- every point inside an open rectangle has a Euclidean ball neighborhood contained in the rectangle

---

*Proof*.

The metric $d$ where $d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) = \sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$ induces the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$; denote this topology $\mathfrak{T}_d$.

To introduce our open rectangles, we let each rectangle $R$ be given by

$$R = \{(x,y): a < x < b, c  < y < d, \hspace{0.3cm} a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R} \}$$

Now, consider $(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathfrak{T}_d)$ and let $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $\varepsilon > 0$. We consider the ball $B_d(x, \varepsilon)$. We know $B_d(x, \varepsilon)$ is $\mathfrak{T}_d$-open. Let $R$ be an open rectangle. We want to show that

$$\forall \, x_0 \in B_d(x, \varepsilon), \exists \, R, x_0 \in R \subset B_d(x, \varepsilon)$$

So let $x_0 \in B_d(x,\varepsilon)$. Since $x_0 \in B_d(x, \varepsilon)$, $d(x,x_0) < \varepsilon$

But from this point, I become stuck. I am trying to come up with a way to utilize $\varepsilon$ somehow to obtain a unique rectangle for every point inside the Euclidean ball. Does anyone have any advice on how to show this direction and/or the other direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take an open ball $B$ centered at $x_0$ and small enough to be contained in $B_d(x, \varepsilon)$ (it exists because every ball is open). Then take an open square centered at $x_0$ and contained in $B$ (for example, with side equal to half the radius of $B$). This works.

The second bullet point is trivial because open rectangles are open in the euclidean topology (spanned by balls).

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$B(A, r) =  \{ P \in \mathbb{R}^2 \hspace{2mm}|\hspace{2mm} d(P, A) < r \}$$
denote the open ball with center $A \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and radius $r \in \mathbb{R}^{>0}$. Also, let $R = (a, b) \times (c, d)$ be the open rectangle such that
$$R = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \hspace{2mm}|\hspace{2mm} a<x<b \hspace{2mm} \text{and} \hspace{2mm} c<y<d \}$$
where $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}.$ We aim to show that for any given open ball $B(A, r)$ and for any point $P \in B(A, r)$, we can find an open rectangle $R$ such that
$$P \in R \subset B(A, r). \hspace{2cm} (1)$$
Say $P = (x, y)$. Since $P \in B(A, r)$, we have
$$d(P, A) < r \iff 0 < r-d(P, A).$$
Consider the open ball with center $(0, 0)$ and radius $r-d(P, A).$ Of course, we can choose a point
$$(a, b) \in B((0,0), r-d(P, A)) $$
such that $a, b > 0.$ We propose that the rectangle $R = (x-a, x+a) \times (y-b, y+b)$ satisfies condition (1). Clearly $P \in R$. Now, let $Q \in R$ be an arbitrary point. Say $Q = (v, w).$ Then we have
$$|x-v|<a$$
and
$$|y-w|<b.$$
Hence, we get
$$d(P,Q) = \sqrt{(x-v)^2 + (y-w)^2} < \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = d((a, b), (0, 0))<r-d(P, A)$$
because the point $(a, b)$ is in the open ball whose center is (0, 0) and whose radius is $r-d(P, A)$. And therefore, we find
$$d(Q, A) \leq d(Q, P) + d(P, A) < r-d(P, A)+d(P, A) = r$$
and $Q \in B(A, r).$ So $R \subset B(A, r)$ and $R$ satisfies condition (1).